# Decompile *.pyc file using uncompyle2

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to decompile *.pyc file using uncompyle2 (https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2). So first step I am doing is cloning git

```
git clone https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2
```

Next step is writing

```
cd uncompyle2/
```

Then

```
python setup.py install
```

Everything is fine, but when I'm trying to write likely command for help

```
uncompyle2 -h
```

It shows only

```
bash: uncompyle2: command not found
```

What I'm doing wrong?

My environment path is: C:\Python27 and my version of python is 2.7.
Python file version which i'm trying to decompile is also 2.7. System is Windows 8.

Comment: Most likely it's in `C:\Python27\Scripts\`, which you probably don't have in your PATH. Something a simple file search could tell you.

Comment: Did you try ```pip install uncompyle2``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `cmd` you need to run the script `uncompyle2` from Scripts folder, that should be in `C:\Python27\Scripts`

From IDLE you could to something like this

```
import uncompyle6

with open("uncompiled file.py", "wb") as fileobj:
    uncompyle6.uncompyle_file("afile.pyc", fileobj)
```

Comment: you could use just any text editor,just open idle,new file then paste the codes and change it accordingly to your needs the the the file as python file and excuse it just as a normal python script

Comment: that is when `os.chdir("C:\Dir\to\where\.pyc_is")` comes in,save the file maybe on the root of C: ,then include its path,for example `os.chdir("C:\afile.pyc")`

Comment: This is my code now: 'import os

os.chdir("C:\mod.pyc")
import uncompyle2
with open("mod.py", "wb") as fileobj:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file("mod.pyc", fileobj)' Script and file are placed in C:\. When I run it, it shows me error about invalid location...

Comment: invalid location of what file?that means it didn't identify you location,what is the location of `mod.py`?

Comment: sorry i meant `mod.pyc` ,so can you post the full error please?

Comment: Here you are. Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 298, in runcode
    exec code in self.locals
  File "C:\run.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.chdir("C:\mod.pyc")
WindowsError: [Error 267] Nazwa katalogu jest nieprawidłowa: 'C:\\mod.pyc'
>>>

Comment: try one more thing,put the both file,the script one and the `mod.pyc` on same folder then just use `("mod.pyc")` then run the script

Comment: Code: import os

os.chdir("C:\Users\andrzej\Desktop\test\mod.pyc")
import uncompyle2
with open("mod.pyc", "wb") as fileobj:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file("mod.py", fileobj)

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 298, in runcode
    exec code in self.locals
  File "C:\Users\andrzej\Desktop\test\run.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.chdir("C:\Users\andrzej\Desktop\test\mod.pyc")
WindowsError: [Error 123] Nazwa pliku, nazwa katalogu lub składnia etykiety woluminu jest niepoprawna: 'C:\\Users\x07ndrzej\\Desktop\test\\mod.pyc'
>>>

Comment: Here you are: https://www.sendspace.com/file/yptqei. And sorry for that :/

Comment: hey i figured out the problem,the module should be run as `uncompyle6` not `uncompyle2` ,,all you have to do is ignore the os module and run the python script on the same folder with the `mod.pyc`,,although i found out the uncompyle is throwing out `Parse error`, i am still trying to figure out a solution for this

Comment: Yes, so I tried decompile easy script, everything is fine. I think this script have something like anti-decompyle (for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b60rqnVneKw). So, thanks for help.

Comment: yes,it is obfuscated  see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410130/uncompyle6-raising-a-parse-error-while-decompile-a-pyc-file> ,i asked a question today and it was explained very clear!