# uncompyle6 raising a parse error while decompile a *.pyc file

Tags: python

While  trying to help a fellow member from this post [Decompile *.pyc file using uncompyle2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407793/decompile-pyc-file-using-uncompyle2/41407984?noredirect=1#comment70021546_41407984), i encountered the following error when trying to decompile  *.pyc using `uncompyle6` , The error is as follows:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/uncompyle6/semantics/pysource.py", line 2231, in build_ast
    raise ParserError(e, tokens)
uncompyle6.semantics.parser_error.ParserError: --- This code section failed: ---

   2       0  JUMP_ABSOLUTE       120  'to 120'
           3  SETUP_WITH          364  'to 370'
           6  STOP_CODE
           7  JUMP_ABSOLUTE       168  'to 168'
          10  SETUP_WITH        22357  'to 22370'
          13  LOAD_CONST            2  ''
          16  LOAD_CONST            2  ''
          19  POP_TOP
          20  RETURN_VALUE
          -1  RETURN_LAST

Parse error at or near `SETUP_WITH' instruction at offset 3
```

Comment: That bytecode makes absolutely no sense. Are you sure you don't have an arbitrary chunk of bytes instead?

Comment: how do i know that as i just see the p-codes,,in fact i don't have the original source!as i said,the guy just sent me the .pyc file,or is obfuscated?

Comment: Perhaps the file is corrupted or compressed? Hard to say from a snippet of invalid decompilation.

Comment: Then let me inform the original OP about this!

Comment: Whenever you see opcode `STOP_CODE` in a disassembly listing, that means that your bytecode/wordcode is faulty. This opcode (value 0) is never used to my knowledge in any Python bytecode and was removed Python 3.3. But when it was defined, it meant "stop execution". I think cleverly they added this opcode with value 0, intentionally for misaligned bytecode since you will find 0 bytes quite a bit in arguments to other instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to decompile (decom*py*le) a piece of arbitrary data. You don't have any *valid* bytecode there, not for a regular Python interpreter.

`JUMP_ABSOLUTE` is used to jump back to the start of loops. It is not used with `with` statements, which is what the `SETUP_WITH` opcode deals with. The jumps are probably outside the code block and in this case *forward* rather than back, so `uncompile6` is correctly flagging this as invalid.

There is a possibility that the bytecode was *obfuscated*, where bytecode meaning is altered from their normal positions. Bytecode is just a sequence of bytes, with each byte given a specific meaning (together with operand values). The Dropbox Python interpreter, for example, has altered that table significantly in an attempt to stop the casual curious engineer from looking at their code (`pydecompyle6` compensates for this).

Comment: oh!thanks for the explanation,i think you also just answered my comment above :)!